# How to add the missing keys in this dictionary with values as empty string using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

the dictionary sample is as below :

```
d = { 1:'',2:'',3:'',5:'',6:'2',7:'',9:'',10:'6',11:'7',13:'9',14:'',15:'11'}
```

and i want to add key 4 with empty string as value after key 3, key 8 with empty string as value after key 7 and so on ....I want the simplest code in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> d = { 1:'',2:'',3:'',5:'',6:'2',7:'',9:'',10:'6',11:'7',13:'9',14:'',15:'11'}
>>> d.update(dict.fromkeys(set(range(16)).difference(d), ''))
>>> d
{0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '2', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '6', 11: '7', 12: '', 13: '9', 14: '', 15: '11'}
```

Note that the dict *is* unordered, even though it may look ordered in this example!

Comment: @Gnibber Thanks Gnibber, Your answer seems useful for me and I will be using it in my application code.

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries do not maintain an order. You cannot add anything 'after' another key.

Just add the keys you are missing:

```
d.update((missing, '') for missing in set(range(1, max(d) + 1)).difference(d))
```

which is a compact way of saying:

```
for index in range(1, max(d) + 1):  # all numbers from 1 to the highest value in the dict
    if index not in d:              # index is missing
        d[index] = ''               # add an empty entry
```

However, it looks more like you need a list instead:

```
alist = [None, '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '6', '7', '', '9', '', '11']
```

where `alist[15]` returns `'11'` just like your `d`. The `None` at the start makes it easier to treat this whit 1-based indexing instead of 0-based, you could adjust your code for that otherwise.

Comment: I suppose you could also use `d.setdefault` in your loop as well to avoid the `index in d` business...

Comment: @mgilson: Since the loop is meant to illustrate what the code above it does, I think `.setdefault()` would only muddle the waters more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It seems that you are generating a list but I need to add my missing keys in the dictionary. The dictionary contains only numeric keys to they can be generated. I think you should take a reference of Above answer.

Comment: @RiturajRamteke: That is what my answer *does*, generate the missing keys. *But*, a dictionary is an inefficient data structure if you wanted to map integers to values, where those integers are in a contiguous sequence. I am advising you to consider using a list instead.

Comment: @RiturajRamteke: the `dict.fromkeys()` method is slightly more efficient, because indeed all that varies here is the keys, not the value, so in that respect gnibbler's solution is better, *for updating your dictionary*.