# How can I create a new column for each item in another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a column called `test` and it is composed by numbers from 1 to 6

```
test
[1,1,1,2,2,3,6]
```

I want to count the numbers and make for each a new column

```
test                01  02   03   04   05   06
[1,1,1,2,2,3,6] => [3]  [2]  [1]  [0]  [0]  [1]
```

[I add an image to make it more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovb0x.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

test = [1,1,1,2,2,3,6]
result = Counter(test)

print(result)
```

The output is a dictionary with the value as `key` and occurrences as `value`:

```
Counter({1: 3,
         2: 2,
         3: 1,
         6: 1})
```

Edit (answer to the comment):

As explained here ([How to add the missing keys in this dictionary with values as empty string using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937327/how-to-add-the-missing-keys-in-this-dictionary-with-values-as-empty-string-using)) you can add missing `keys` with value `0` very simply:

```
max_value = max(result.keys()) + 1
result.update(dict.fromkeys(set(range(1,max_value)).difference(result), 0))

print(result)
```

Here `max_value` denote the max `value` of the `keys` in the dictionary. The output will be:

```
Counter({1: 3,
         2: 2,
         3: 1,
         6: 1,
         4: 0,
         5: 0})
```

Comment: But what can i do if i would like to count every line. I also uploaded an image.